# Crystal Report 13.0.2000.0 - How to extend maximum large more than 200 inches

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to extend the maximum large of a Crystal Reports more than 200 inches.
The version of Crystal Reports is 13.0.2000.0 and I am using Visual Studio 2015.

When I try to do so I get a message that says "Page size ranges from 0 to 200; Enter valid page size".

How can I enlarge the page large?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtmBj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such possibility. The 200 inches for page width set based on market standards.

See SAP Note 2348254
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2737559